# Creating a HashMap in Rust using the fold iterator method

Tags: rust, hashmap, iterator

I am trying to create a word count HashMap from an array of words using [Entry](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/hash_map/enum.Entry.html) and iterators in Rust. When I try as below,

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
fn main () {
    let corpus = ["foo", "bar", "bar", "grok", "blah", "foo", "bar"];
    let mut word_count = corpus.iter().fold(HashMap::new(), |mut acc, word| *acc.entry(word).or_insert(0) += 1);
    println!("{:?}", word_count);
}
```

I get the error: **expected struct `HashMap`, found `()`, type mismatch**.

I can get it to work by creating a new scope and explicitly returning the accumulator as:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
fn main () {
    let corpus = ["foo", "bar", "bar", "grok", "blah", "foo", "bar"];
    let mut word_count = corpus.iter().fold(HashMap::new(), |mut acc, word|{
        *acc.entry(word).or_insert(0) += 1;
        acc
    });
    println!("{:?}", word_count);
}
```

and I get the expected `{"foo": 2, "bar": 3, "blah": 1, "grok": 1}`.

Usually `fold` returns the last state of the accumulator, so I was expecting the first approach to work, and am unclear why it does not. Would really appreciate some clarification and any suggestions on alternative approaches (using iterators).

Comment: The closure passed into fold is of type `FnMut(B, Self::Item) -> B`, which means the accumulator is moved into the closure scope (rather than being passed in as a mutable reference), and the closure is expected to return the modified accumulator. The type of the expression `*acc.entry(word).or_insert(0) += 1` is the unit type `()`, so the compiler rightly marks this an an error.

Comment: Ah, I see. Do I understand correctly that since ```*acc.entry(word).or_insert(0) += 1``` is a statement, in the first case the closure isn't actually returning anything, whereas it should be returning the modified accumulator as it does in the second?

Comment: @Py_Dream Technically, this is an expression returning `()`, but you can think of it as a statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like explained in the comment from @PitaJ, `*acc.entry(word).or_insert(0) += 1` has the type `()` while the compiler expects `fold()`'s callback to return the next state each time (it is sometimes called `reduce()` in other languages, e.g. [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce); in Rust; `fold()`  allows you to specify the start value while `reduce()` takes it from the first item in the iterator).

Because of this, I feel like it is more appropriate use case for a loop, since you don't need to return a new state but to update the map:

```rust
let mut word_count = HashMap::new();
for word in &corpus {
    *word_count.entry(word).or_insert(0) += 1;
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3c3c38557aa3687a543fc7e2e07b193f).

However, if you want, there is a method in the `itertools` crate that does exactly that: [`counts()`](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.counts):

```rust
let word_count = corpus.iter().counts();
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a5ae99776bf4778610e76a5c14c819f6).

Comment: Thank you for the response and the alternative you proposed! My reason for preferring iterators was that it would be easier to parallelize it with rayon. Do you happen to know if itertools methods can operate on parallel iterators from rayon?

Comment: @Py_Dream Unfortunately, they don't. Though if you want to parallelize it you likely need to replace the map, too: `HashMap` does not allow you shared mutation (`entry()` takes `&mut self`), and using a mutex will probably be worth than sequential execution. You can use [`DashMap`](https://docs.rs/dashmap/latest/dashmap/struct.DashMap.html) from the `dashmap` crate.

Comment: Oh nice! Hadn't considered that. Thanks a ton for the idea.